# Distinct values in listBox and SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#

I have a listbox where I need to display distinct labels.

```
public void LoadContent()
{
    TDFnEtlGetTargetVariableList tdFnEtlGetTargetVariableList =                   
        TDFunctions.FnEtlGetTargetVariable.Execute(database, SelectedExportConnectionId, lang, false);

    lstTargetVariable.DataSource = tdFnEtlGetTargetVariableList.Items.Select(a => a.Label).Distinct().ToList(); ;
    lstTargetVariable.DisplayMember = "Label";
}
```

However, when I write it as in the code below, on the line `TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable selectedTargetVariable =(TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable)lstTargetVariable.SelectedItem;` it tells me that "object of type System.String cannot be converted to type TDFnGetTargetVariable (TDFnGetTargetVariable is DataRow).

```
private void LstTargetVariable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                

    TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable selectedTargetVariable = (TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable)lstTargetVariable.SelectedItem;

    TargetVariableMetadataJson targetVariableMetadataJson = new TargetVariableMetadataJson();
    targetVariableMetadataJson.LoadFromText(selectedTargetVariable.MetadataString);

    cmbStateOrChange.DataSource = targetVariableMetadataJson.Data;
    cmbStateOrChange.DisplayMember = "state_or_change_label_cz";

    cmbUnit.DataSource = targetVariableMetadataJson.Data;
    cmbUnit.DisplayMember = "unit_label_cz";
}
```

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: To reiterate the error, your list contains strings not TDFnEtlGetTargetVariables. Maybe you want to access the selected index and use that to get the data row from your DataSource.

Comment: I apologize for my very limited knowledge and thank you for your response. If I remove this: .Select(a => a.Label).Distinct().ToList() I don't have distinct labels, but the code works. But I would need the labels distinct.

Comment: There is an overload to `Distinct` that takes an EqualityComparer. You can implement one that uses the label in the comparison logic so that your result will have the objects you want instead of just strings. [See example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Crowcoder! I have already tried EqualityComparer, but I wrote it wrong. I tried it again and right this time!
The result is:

```cs
public class TDFnEtlGetTargetVariableComparer : IEqualityComparer<TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable>
{
    public bool Equals(TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable x, TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable y)
    {
        return x.Label == y.Label;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TDFnEtlGetTargetVariable obj)
    {
        return obj.Label.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

```cs
public void LoadContent()
{
    TDFnEtlGetTargetVariableList tdFnEtlGetTargetVariableList =
               TDFunctions.FnEtlGetTargetVariable.Execute(database, SelectedExportConnectionId, lang, false);

    lstTargetVariable.DataSource = tdFnEtlGetTargetVariableList.Items.Distinct(new TDFnEtlGetTargetVariableComparer()).ToList();
    lstTargetVariable.DisplayMember = "Label";
}
```

I am very sorry for the bad formatting of the code, but it just goes as this when I paste the copied code and I do not know how to do the correct indentation.